# How to add *.jack in android studio?

Tags: android, jack

In android M, android support jack, and I compile the library and it is 3d.jack instead of 3d.jar.

My question is how to add 3d.jack as the library to build my app which depends on the library of 3d.

I know how to add a lib if the lib is 3d.jar. But I try to use same way, copy 3d.jack into libs folder, and change to *.jack, it doesn't work.

So anyone knows how to do it?

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jack'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
}
```

Comment: http://code2care.org/pages/import-external-jars-to-android-studio-project/

Comment: try this dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.tools.jack:jack-api:0.9.0'
}

Comment: my question is how to add jack lib from android studio? To use jack compile i know is to add jackoptions.enable =true, then i will use jack, but how to link .jack as library?

Answer (score 4):

I have a workground method.
In the module where it make the .jack file, you can add 
LOCAL_JACK_ENABLED := disabled
in the make file.Then it will generate .jar instead of .jack.
Then you can use the .jar as usual.